# Are the "the 28 pages" and "Justice Against Sponsors of Terrorism Act" interrelated?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, terrorism, saudi-arabia

We know that US news of "[The 28 pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_28_Pages)" and "[Justice Against Sponsors of Terrorism Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Against_Sponsors_of_Terrorism_Act)" were spread almost at the same time period and both of them concerned Saudi Arabia interests.

Now, can we say that US tried to send some messages to Saudi Arabia via releasing those 28 pages and by passing 'Justice Against Sponsors of Terrorism Act'? In other words can we say that US were trying to control Saudi Arabis by those 2 items?
Thanks

Comment: What's the question here?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Bobson I edited the post so that the question is more clear now!

Comment: Even after the edits, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @SamIam If you could tell me what part seems vague to you then I would do the disambiguation.

Comment: @MohammadHossein  It's not that it's vague.  It's that the words literally don't make sense.